# How does a new node join a group in the SWIM protocol?

Tags: distributed-system

P.s. I have already had a look at [SWIM protocol how does a new node get an address of an existing node in a cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741917/swim-protocol-how-does-a-new-node-get-an-address-of-an-existing-node-in-a-cluste) and my question asks a little bit more than that, which is why made a separate post.

I am trying to implement the SWIM protocol in c, and I have two questions:
1) How does a node get introduced into the group? From what I can think of, I'm guessing a standard "introducer" node sends the member list over to the new node and starts gossiping about the node joining the cluster?
And
2) What happens if the "introducer" node fails? How is a new introducer elected? I'm thinking maybe Paxos but its too complicated for me to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new node member selects a random subset of peers(seed members) of cluster as targets for gossip messages while joining the cluster based on the configuration provided to it. The address of at least one alive node member / seed member address of the cluster must be known to the new node member so that it can join the cluster. In case the seed member (introducer) gets killed at the initial stage, there is no other way for the new node to convey its existence and it shall become isolated unless there is alternate seed address in subset that is alive and known to the new node member. However, if the seed member (introducer) gets killed at a stage where the initial gossip of new node has been communicated to another node of the cluster, there shall not be much impact unless the new node is required for sure to reach a specific another node.

Once joined, the other nodes shall introduce it to gossips, this allows the new node member to gradually receive information about all the nodes of the cluster. The “gossip information” that new node is added is included in the packets such as (ping, ping-req, ack) that is used by the protocol to send messages to other nodes at regular intervals which is termed as “infection-style” dissemination mechanism.
Accordingly, the membership list maintained by each node member shall get updated whenever a new node member joins or leaves the cluster.